# Node JS no me reconoce los import y export

Tags: nodejs, express, javascript-import

estoy haciendo una pequeña api con NodeJS y express al principio funcionaba bien, pero luego decidí separar el código en distintos archivos para tenerlo más ordenado, utilicé module.exports para exportar la función que levanta el servidor, pero en el otro archivo me sale el error app.server is not a function
Este es el app.js, la función server es la que me da problemas.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const json = require('../datos.json');
const  bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('port', 3000);

const server = () => {
    app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
        console.log(`Hola mundo desde el puerto: ${app.get('port')}`);
    });
}

module.exports = server;
```

Y este es el index.js, cuando intenté poner más abajo el app.server me dio el error app.get is not a function.

```
const app = require('./src/app');



const middelware = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Esto es un middelware');
    next();
}

const middelware2 = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Segundo middelware');
    next();
}


app.get('/', middelware, middelware2, (req, res) => {
    return res.send({
        "mensaje" : "Hola mundo desde nodeJS"
    });
});
```

Cuando junto todo en el mismo archivo todo funciona perfectamente, el problema viene cuando los separo en archivos diferentes.

Este es el error que me sale cuando llamo a la función app.server al final  del archivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el error que me sale cuando lo llamo al principio del archivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cual puede ser el error? Gracias.

Comment: El error es claro, estás exportando una función llamada `server` y no una `app` de Express, debes exportar directamente `app` o simplemente inyectar tus Middlewares en el `server`. En todo caso, el envoltorio (*wrapper*) que estás creando alrededor de `app` hace imposible que puedas usar directamente `app`. En mi opinión está de más. Saludos

Comment: ¿Y cómo puedo solucionar eso? Empecé ayer con node y aún no sé mucho, gracias por la ayuda